# New router configured with WDS causing instability

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wds

My main/existing wifi router is an Asus RT-AC68U. I have configured 2G and 5G to use the said SSID/password -- it's been working fine. I've just added a TP-Link Archer A6 in an adjoining room and configured it to act as a range extender, to add wired connection to some devices that are in that area. The setup is as follows:

**Facts**

- Archer A6 does work, and provides internet access to the wired devices via WDS / wifi
- other wireless devices work for a while but some wireless devices stop working (no internet) at some point, for instance...

  - phone works fine (with cellular data off)
  - laptops will work for a while and then stop
  - laptops will report "no internet", but remain connected to wifi, after some time
  - turning off the Archer A6 immediately solves wifi issues with laptops

Seems like the Archer A6 is working okay but eventually loses its route to the internet, meanwhile devices are deciding to connect to it instead of the other AP because the signal is stronger. **My goal is to have the Archer A6 device only act as a "wireless adapter".** E.g. connect to the existing wifi AP (Asus), but not broadcast its SSID or allow wireless connections at all. I only want to essentially give network access to wired devices, but without running ethernet to that area of the room.

```
internet]--[Surfboard SB6183]--[EdgeRouter X]--[RT-AC68U)  (Archer A6]--[wired devices
                                                                     )  (wireless devices

]--[ == wired connection
)  ( == wireless connection
```

**Archer A6 Config**

Followed this guide: https://community.tp-link.com/us/home/forum/topic/175380

- WDS on, attached to RT-AC68U's 5G SSID / MAC
- same control channel, channel bandwidth, and extension channel as RT-AC68U's 5G SSID
- 2.4G disabled entirely

Comment: Try updating the firmware in both routers and then restart both.

Comment: What version number is the archer A6?

Comment: v2. I did just replace my main router with an EAP225 so I'm waiting to see if the issue is resolved.